# Play Framework 2.5.12 - Get Method from Call

Tags: java, reflection, playframework

i need to get the method called from **play.api.mvc.Call** instance.
I have noted the methods of my controllers and using reverse routing i need to check Those annotations.

I'm using Play Framework 2.5.12

Example:

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface MyAnnotation{
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

    @MyAnnotation
    public Result home(int index){
      return ok(index);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class MyClass{

    private Call call;

    public MyClass(Call call){
      this.call = call;
    }

    public boolean hasAnnotation(){
      //TODO
      return call.getControllerMethod().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(routes.MyController.home(1));
if(obj.hasAnnotation()){
  //do something
}
```

Clearly `call.getControllerMethod()` does not exist but i need some solution to obtain the method of controllers from URL or Call Instance.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

Unfortunately I resolved creating a Call wrapper like this:

```
public class CallRef extends Call {

    private Class<? extends Controller> controllerClass;
    private Method controllerMethod;

    public CallRef(Call call, Class<? extends Controller> controllerClass,
                   String controllerMethodName, Class<?>... methodArgs) throws NoSuchMethodException {

        this(call, controllerClass, controllerClass.getMethod(controllerMethodName, methodArgs));
    }

    public CallRef(Call call, Class<? extends Controller> controllerClass, Method controllerMethod) {
        this(call.method(), call.url(), call.fragment(), controllerClass, controllerMethod);
    }

    public CallRef(String method, String url, String fragment, Class<? extends Controller> controllerClass, Method controllerMethod) {
        super(method, url, fragment);
        this.controllerClass = controllerClass;
        this.controllerMethod = controllerMethod;
    }

    public CallRef(CallRef callRef){
            this(callRef, callRef.getControllerClass(), callRef.getControllerMethod());
    }

    public Class<? extends Controller> getControllerClass() {
        return controllerClass;
    }

    public Method getControllerMethod() {
        return controllerMethod;
    }
}
```

So I need manually create instance on my class `CallRef` specifying controllers, method and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `play.api.mvc.Call` is for Scala, Java uses `play.mvc.Call`.

**2.** `Call` describes an HTTP request. You can't use it to get annotation from the controller method. Just use simple reflection as in any other case for getting annotation.

**UPDATE**

You can get the route, then look which pattern represents your URL and then check the annotation by reflection

```
import com.google.inject.Provider;
import play.routing.Router;
import play.routing.Router.RouteDocumentation;

...

@Inject 
private Provider<Router> router;

...

List<RouteDocumentation> docs = router.get().documentation();
for(RouteDocumentation doc: docs){
    String protocol = doc.getHttpMethod();
    Sting pathPattern =  doc.getPathPattern();
    String methodStrign = doc.getControllerMethodInvocation());

    // Check the pathPattern against url
    // Get the annotation from the methodStrign by reflection.
}
```

Comment: Ok, i know that Call describes a HTTP request but there is any way to get Method instance(or alternately Method name, Controller name and parameters class list) by url ? 
Practically i need to do the work that Play do when recives a client HTTP request: from url i need to know what method need to be called.Thanks

Comment: i.e. you want to annotate the method with something like  @url("/myurl/here")  and then call that method if the URL is in the request?

Comment: I wont call method but i need only to know his annotaions.
I need to do this when application startup, i have a list of URL/Call and iterating it i need todo some actions if method related at url/Call has annotations

Comment: I am afraid, you will need to parse the route file, see my update.

Comment: I suspected unfortunately, i have tried this way but i have had some problems matching path pattern with parameters and with reflection call without knowing parameters classes

Comment: Indeed.  How do you receive the `Call` objects? You need to know the method path and signature to do it, like `Call call = controllers.routes.HomeController.index()`, so you already must know the controller  method exactly.

Comment: Unfortunately i resolved creating wrapper, it's not a great solution but work